# Searching issue in DNN 7.1

Tags: dotnetnuke

I have worked on dnn 7.1 . I have use the search code like this.

```
<dnn:SEARCH ID="dnnSearch" runat="server" ShowSite="false"
 ShowWeb="false" EnableTheming="true" Submit="Search"
 CssClass="SearchButton" />
```

but in this only search the pages in the site not search the documents in the site.
Please any one help me..

Answer (score 0):

Document search is something that will be dependent on the modules you are using and the edition of DotNetNuke that you are using.

How are your documents stored?

Comment: I worked on dnn 7.1 and search result module 7.1.0.
how to find documents stored location?
I only simply create skins and use skins add the pages and text  module on page, perform the search on the content.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using DNN Professional, or the community version? DNN 7.1 Pro version indexes documents and site pages. The community version indexes site pages only.

Answer (score 0):

DNN by default does not search documents (pdf, doc, xls etc). Your best bet is to get one of the modules that uses the Lucene search/index engine. I had to do this years ago to index the content of documents for the DNN search (back in version 4). It worked okay and I imagine the process has only gotten better.

This is one that uses it: http://store.dnnsoftware.com/home/product-details/dnn-search-engine-pssitesearch-2029

Comment: Last time i am using DNN 7.0. In this version not problem in the search.

Comment: @jitendra - sorry dont understand your comment